# WordPress wp-config.php if-else is not working on some computers

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, if-statement

I have the same wp-config in local and remote setups.

The code below checks if user is loading the local or the live -version of the site, and uses appropriate database credentials:

```
/* 
 * Unified variables 
 */   
$hostname = 'localhost';  
$chartset = 'utf8';  
*etcetc....

/* 
 * Check for the current environment 
 */  
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] === 'example.dev') {  
  $db_name = 'example';  
  $user_name = 'root'; 
  $password = 'root';  
} else 
{  
  $db_name = 'remote_db_name';
  $user_name = 'remote_db_user';
  $password = 'remote_db_pw; 
}  
 
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //  
/** The name of the database for WordPress */  
define('DB_NAME', $db_name);  
  
/** MySQL database username */  
define('DB_USER', $user_name);  
//etc....
```

This one works. But if I flip the if command other way around so its

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] === 'example.com') {  
  $db_name = 'example';  
  $user_name = 'root'; 
  $password = 'root';  
} else 
{  
  $db_name = 'remote_db_name';
  $user_name = 'remote_db_user';
  $password = 'remote_db_pw; 
}
```

it works for me with several different devices and connections, but for my client it no longer works. Any ideas why this could be?

I need it to be the other way around because I'm testing my designs with other devices with urls like:
http://example.dev.192.168.1.3.xip.io and it would be better if all the instenses of local development like example.dev and http://example.dev.192.168.1.3.xip.io would be the "else" -case in the if-else.

What could lead to database error on my client? He has tried several devices and connections and the problem goes away if the live-server is in the "else" case and not the

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] === 'example.com') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider something like:

```
if ( stristr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'example.dev' ) ) {

}
```

This will work for the examples you gave above. You could even try example.com as the needle. I'm curious as to whether www. would show up in the HTTP_HOST. If so could this be why your client is having an issue?

Comment: Nice one! Indeed I echoed the $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST" on my site and my client was browsing the www-version of the site. Because I'm using the last solution on http://support.clickontyler.com/a/21/wordpress-liftoff/ it makes the automatic wordpress redirects stop working.